# Need to rebuild Boot sector and Partition table of a once Multiboot Disk manually converted to VMDK

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, boot-partition, vmdk, bootsector

I **had a problem with an HD that was not in a Healthy State** I was able to make a backup in time with Acronis Image Home.
The backup was partial, the original Disk had 4 partition (3 primary, bootable partitions and a logical only Data partition), the was a bootmanager to boot respectively Windows 7(1), Windows Vista(2), WindowsXP(3). I made a backup of only W7 partition and the DATA partition.

I didn't need the old Vista and WinxP drives, and that's why **I made partial backup, not disk backup**.

**I want to virtualize the old machine**.
Using VMware vCenter Converter I wasn't able to convert the tib file, it gave error, probably because that was only a partial backup of first and last partition.

So I chose to follow a different path, **I mounted the TIB file**, which mounted the two partitions as separate disks, then **using EASE Backup, I made a backup of the first(Window 7) partition and converted the image to VMDK.**

Now I've created a Workstation 9 VMX(Using VMWARE Trial), which asked me to convert the VMDK to 9.0 version (I said NO). I will convert the data partition later.

**Powering ON the Virtual Machine It booted to the boot manager**, but obviously it doesn't work, whatever boot option I choose **I get this error**:

*Status: 0xc000000e*

*Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.*

If I remember well using VMware converter, the software takes care of the machine conversion including controller drivers used when the machine was installed on the real hardware.

Now I need to solve this problem, and **I need advices to make all steps safe and working without any troubles**.

For sure Boot sectors and partition table must be updated to reflect a disk with only a partition, and also need to solve the problem of all the drivers installed in the system that could give problem.

I've Windows 7 Install DVD and can try to use some utils to fix it but never made this so I need guidance.

**UPDATE**

Used W7 Install Disk and repaired Boot, removing all other partition, now the system starts to load but I get a **BSOD**...

*Status: 0x0000007B*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution here:

http://communities.vmware.com/message/2183682#2183682

Resuming: You need to make sure that **Logic SAS Scsi controller** is setup on your VM VMX file, and that the VMDK drive you have to boot from is setup to run on that controller.

Finally to solve the BSOD **you need to modify the Guest OS Registry**, you can do this with a live cd that can load Windows, a recovery cd or **whatever can load Regedit** or other Registry tools, the you select the Guest OS System Hive, and change **HKLM/ControlSet001\services\LSI_SAS**, then **set the start type to REG_DWORD 0**(Mine was 3 before changing it to 0), unload the Hive and all is done, you need to **reboot** and delete any driver that is not useful anymore(in the VM) and finally install VMWare Tools.